# VB.NET Store Image error: A generic error occurred in GDI+ (Updated)

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms

I use pathstring to store and get image in database.

When I select new image to replace old image, it prompt out error:

**1. A generic error occurred in GDI+**

I google search out that one of the possible answer is that it cannot replace the old image with new image with same path. But I still wish to store and replace the old image to new image with one same path for a clean image management.

I try to use a trick which is to save the new image with a different path name, delete the old image, then rename the new image to the original path. But the system don't allow me to delete the old image as it being used by other process.

I repost this as I may describe the question not clearly from my last post. I hope this post can provide more detail about my question.

Hope some expert can provide the solution. Thank you.

**Code to load data into my form**

```
Private Sub FrmEditConcert_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim concertID As String = lblConcert.Text.Substring(0, 8)
        Dim chosenDB As New MusicDataContext
        Dim selected As concert = (From o In chosenDB.concerts
                                   Where o.concert_id = concertID).FirstOrDefault

        Dim pathString As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(selected.image)

        txtEditName.Text = selected.name
        txtEditDescription.Text = selected.description
        cboEditTime.SelectedItem = selected.time
        dtpEditDate.Value = selected.date.Date
        pcbEditImage.Image = Image.FromFile(pathString)
End Sub
```

**Code to save data to database and save image with path**

```
Private Sub btnEditConcert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditConcert.Click
        'Create path, prepare store in database 
         Dim concertID As String = lblConcert.Text.Substring(0, 8)
         Dim editName As String = concertID & ".jpg"
         Dim folder As String = "C:\Users\e-default\Desktop\assignment\Uploaded Image"
         Dim pathString As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, editName)

         'Generate new concert
         Dim db As New MusicDataContext()
         Dim c = (From o In db.concerts
                  Where o.concert_id = concertID).FirstOrDefault

         c.name = txtEditName.Text
         c.description = txtEditDescription.Text
         c.time = cboEditTime.SelectedItem
         c.date = dtpEditDate.Value
         c.image = pathString
         db.SubmitChanges()

         'Save image to folder (Error occurs here)
         pcbEditImage.Image.Save(pathString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you loading from and saving to the same path?

Comment: Load the initial Image like this: `pcbEditImage.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(pathString)))`

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes